# How to make an IF to match non-boolean in Google Tables?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an url like http://example.com/url.xml, where i have differend nodes, like

```
<1>
    <desc>one two</desc>
    <link>three four</link>
</1>

<2>
    <desc>five six</desc>
    <link>seven eight</link>
</2>

<3>
    <desc>nine ten</desc>
    <link>eleven twelwe</link>
</3>
```

I want to search in  for an existence of a term, and, in case of match, extract the whole pair of desc and link.

Maybe anyhow like this - but i struggle with correct syntax: `IF <desc>([^>]*)</desc> contains "two" → extract <desc>([^>]*)</desc> into B2 AND extract <link>([^>]*)</link> into C2`

I was trying to do so:

```
=IF(importxml(A1,"//desc[contains(.,'two')]"),importxml(A1,"//desc|//link))"),"")
```

But get this error

```
Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'two' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.
```

This one `=importxml(A1,"//*[contains(text(),'consent')]|//Link")` ends with an error too:

```
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C2.
```

No luck today...

Comment: If you are able to use RegEx within google sheets, you may try the following. I am searching for matches of **two** only within the description and capturing the desc and link text if there is a match.

`(?<=<desc>)(.*?two.*?)(?=<[\n\w\W]*?link>(.*)<)`

Answer (score 2):

Finally this worked for me:

```
=importxml(A1,"//*[contains(.,'two')]/desc")    =importxml(A1,"//*[contains(.,'two')]/link")
```